# Flutter Todo returns null at title = widget.title

Tags: flutter, dart

I am having a problem with that my Todolist that returns error message:                      "A non-null String must be provided to a Text widget.
'package:flutter/src/widgets/text.dart':
Failed assertion: line 360 pos 10: 'data != null' " and its in class MyHomePage at line     title: new Text(widget.title. I have already tried to change it to title: new Text(widget.title??""), but that does not work. Any other solution that can work?

```
   void main() => runApp(new MyApp());
    
    class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return new MaterialApp(
          title: 'Todos',
          theme: new ThemeData(primarySwatch: Colors.deepOrange),
          home: new MyHomePage(title: 'Todos'),
        );
      }
    }
    class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
      MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);
      final String title;
      @override
      MyHomePageState createState() => new MyHomePageState();
    }
    
    class MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
      
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return new Scaffold(
          appBar:  new AppBar(
            title: new Text(widget.title),
          ),
          body: TodoList(),
        );
      }
    }

class TodoList extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() => TodoListState();
}

class TodoListState extends State {
  DbHelper helper = DbHelper();
  List<Todo> todos;
  int count = 0;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    if (todos == null) {
      todos = List<Todo>();
      getData();
    }
    return Scaffold(
      body: todoListItems(),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
          onPressed: () {
            navigateToDetail(Todo('', 3, ''));
          },
          tooltip: "Add new Todo",
          child: new Icon(Icons.add)),
    );
  }

  ListView todoListItems() {
    return ListView.builder(
      itemCount: count,
      itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int position) {
        return Card(
          color: Colors.white,
          elevation: 2,
          child: ListTile(
            leading: CircleAvatar(
              backgroundColor: getColor(this.todos[position].priority),
              child: Text(this.todos[position].priority.toString()),
            ),
            title: Text(this.todos[position].title),
            subtitle: Text(this.todos[position].date),
            onTap: () {
              debugPrint("Tapped on " + this.todos[position].id.toString());
              navigateToDetail(this.todos[position]);
            },
          ),
        );
      },
    );
  }

  void getData() {
    final dbFuture = helper.initializeDb();
    dbFuture.then((result) {
      final todosFuture = helper.getTodos();
      todosFuture.then((result) {
        List<Todo> todoList = List<Todo>();
        count = result.length;
        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
          todoList.add(Todo.fromObject(result[i]));
          debugPrint(todoList[i].title);
        }
        setState(() {
          todos = todoList;
          count = count;
        });
        debugPrint("Items " + count.toString());
      });
    });
  }

  Color getColor(int priority) {
    switch (priority) {
      case 1:
        return Colors.red;
        break;
      case 2:
        return Colors.orange;
        break;
      case 3:
        return Colors.green;
        break;
      default:
        return Colors.green;
    }
  }

  void navigateToDetail(Todo todo) async {
    bool result = await Navigator.push(
      context,
      MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => TodoDetail(todo)),
    );
    if (result == true) {
      getData();
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I've run the portion of the code where you say your error is and it shows no errors locally. This is a very basic error of missing data and cannot be complicated. Especially when it's something hardcoded. You are only passing a string from one class to another, there's not much room for failure. Are you sure this is the line that has the error?

Comment: It worked with                                                                                                              child: Text(this.todos[position].priority.toString() ?? ""),
        title: Text(this.todos[position].title ?? "" ),
        subtitle: Text(this.todos[position].date ?? "" ) in every text so can now see my todo with date and Id. However title is still null and not displayed in todo. So need to look at that.

Answer (score 0):

please change this line `title: new Text(widget.title),` to `title: new Text(widget.title??""),`

`first ?? ""` this is a null check ... when first is null returns `""`

---

**Edit**

and please repeat this way for all Text widget

```
        child: Text(this.todos[position].priority.toString() ?? ""),
        title: Text(this.todos[position].title ?? "" ),
        subtitle: Text(this.todos[position].date ?? "" ),
```

Comment: title: new Text(widget.title??"") does not work and I can see that my todo are populated in debug console. Debug console:                                                                              flutter: Items 4
Another exception was thrown: A non-null String must be provided to a Text widget.

Comment: @DavidRuland This Error From Text Widget ... I Edited The Answer .